# how to install ffmpeg via brew on mac os?

Tags: ffmpeg, homebrew

Is it possible to install ffmpeg via brew?

brew install ffmpeg

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools for Xcode release is available
You should install the latest version from: http://connect.apple.com
==> Installing ffmpeg dependency: texi2html
==> Downloading http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz 
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mirror.yongbok.net; nodename nor servname provided, or not known 
Error: Download failed: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz
```

brew install texi2html

```
Warning: A newer Command Line Tools for Xcode release is available
You should install the latest version from: http://connect.apple.com
 ==> Downloading http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz 
######################################################################## 100.0%
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mirror.yongbok.net; nodename nor servname provided, or not known
Error: Download failed: http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible to install ffmpeg via Homebrew. In your case it appears the XCode developer tools needs to be installed/updated. Once updated you can install via 'brew install ffmpeg' from the Terminal app.

Comment: unfortunately, I have the same error after updating xcode.

Comment: On Ventura 13.1 (22C65) with xcode pre-installed, `brew install ffmpeg` worked off the bat.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1) Search working mirror http://www.filewatcher.com/m/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz.7350232-0.html
=> for example ftp://ftp.mirrorservice.org/sites/distfiles.macports.org/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz

2) Put this path to url tag in /usr/local/Library/Formula/texi2html.rb

3) Calc shasum for texi2html-1.82.tar.gz (its e7bbe1197147566250abd5c456b94c8e37e0a81f) and put it in sha1 tag in /usr/local/Library/Formula/texi2html.rb

Now brew install ffmpeg works ok

Answer (score -1):

### Yep, it is helpful, awesome

#### vi /usr/local/Library/Formula/texi2html.rb

`class Texi2html < Formula
  desc "Convert TeXinfo files to HTML"
  homepage "http://www.nongnu.org/texi2html/"
  url "ftp://ftp.gnome.org/mirror/gnu.org/savannah/texi2html/texi2html-1.82.tar.gz"
  sha256 "6c7c94a2d88ffe218a33e91118c2b039336cbe3f2f8b4e3a78e4fd1502072936"`